# java.util.Scanner Issue with CTRL+Z, CTRL+C, CTRL+X

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on a project that requires receiving and processing inputs from console. I use eclipse and accidentally discovered that when I press CTRL+Z in my console (without pressing ENTER after), the program crashes with a NoSuchElementException which I believe was thrown by the `Scanner.nextLine()` method. Below is the stripped down version of it.

Test.java

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String input = "";
        while(true) {
            System.out.printf("Say something: ");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            String output = input.trim().toUpperCase();
            
            if(output.equals("Q")) {
                break;
            }
            
            System.out.printf("Uppercase: %s\n", output);
        }
        
        scanner.close();
    }
    
}
```

Here is my test run:

```
Say something: hey
Uppercase: HEY
Say something: i'm boutta crash this program by pressing ctrl+z
Uppercase: I'M BOUTTA CRASH THIS PROGRAM BY PRESSING CTRL+Z
Say something: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1656)
    at Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

I also compiled the .java file with `javac Test.java` and run with `java Test` in Windows Command Prompt. Here is the output.

```
C:\>cd Test

C:\Test>javac Test.java

C:\Test>java Test
Say something: i'm gonna press ctrl+c
Uppercase: I'M GONNA PRESS CTRL+C
Say something: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
^C
C:\Test>
```

Are there any way to prevent CTRL+Z and CTRL+V from being read by the scanner? Thank you in advance for any help/explanations.

I tried surrounding the line `input = scanner.nextLine();` with try/catch block. Here is my attempt.

```
try {
                input = scanner.nextLine();
            } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
                scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.printf("caught NoSuchElementException\n");
            }
```

I got an infinite loop.

```
Say something: pressing ctrl+z...
Uppercase: PRESSING CTRL+Z...
Say something: caught NoSuchElementException
Uppercase: PRESSING CTRL+Z...
Say something: caught NoSuchElementException
Uppercase: PRESSING CTRL+Z...
Say something: caught NoSuchElementException
Uppercase: PRESSING CTRL+Z...
...
```

Comment: ctrl-Z is the windows EOF character

Comment: @tgdavies is the EOF character the same as "End of Text" (ASCII 003), or "End of Transmission" (ASCII 004), or neither?

Comment: I mean that it causes the Scanner to report that it can't read any more characters

Answer (score 1):

ctrl+z in windows or ctrl-d in Linux are DOS commands for the end of input. So, if you deploy your program in Linux, it will behave the same for the input of *ctrl-d*. You should handle this by calling method `scanner.hasNextLine()` which returns true only if there is input. I have attached the modified program, it runs. You may refer.

```
public class ControlPlusZ {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String input = "";
    while(true) {
        System.out.printf("Say something: ");
        if(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.hasNextLine());
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        String output = input.trim().toUpperCase();
        
        if(output.equals("Q")) {
            break;
        }
        
        
        System.out.printf("Uppercase: %s\n", output);
    }
        else {System.out.println("Closing scanner");
            
            break;}}
    
    scanner.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you but are there any way to continue receiving input from the user?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer like @Rajnish's, and after some tinkering to test how it would work, I have a solution:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Say something: ");

            // THIS IS MY SOLUTION
            if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                break;
            }
            
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            String output = input.trim().toUpperCase();
            
            if (output.equals("Q")) {
                break;
            }
            
            System.out.printf("Uppercase: %s\n", output);
        }
        
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Basically, this tells the Scanner that we want the input to be a newline-delimited String, but we don't actually take input yet ([from the Java docs, "[The] scanner does not advance past any input."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--)). If the user did input a String, then the `input = scanner.nextLine();` would take in that input. However, if the user input something different (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), then the `!scanner.hasNextLine()` would be true, breaking the user from the loop.